# Which design pattern to use?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I was asked in a recent interview:

A Sandwich should have exactly two slices of bread
(one on each end), and any positive number of Cheeses in between.

```
Sandwich s = new Sandwich();
s.add(new BreadSlice());
s.add(new CheddarCheese());
s.add(new SwissCheese());
s.add(new BreadSlice());
System.println("My sandwich: "+ s.toString());
```

What design pattern could you use to ensure that every Sandwich instantiated is a valid sandwich?

Comment: In the moment of the instantiation each sandwich is not valid.

Comment: But every sandwich instantiated is *not* a valid sandwich. It's not valid until some unknown time after instantiation, when the necessary adds are called. This is itself a design smell.

Comment: I guess we'll take that question off the interview pre-screen test now ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use a `Builder` pattern: *Used for very complicated multi-step object construction, where the number of constructor or method arguments would be ridiculously high.*

```
SandwichBuilder sb = new SandwichBuilder();
sb.addFirstBread(new BreadSlice());
sb.addCheese(new Cheese());
...
sb.addLastBread(new BreadSlice());
Sandwich s = sb.getSandwich();
```

incomplete `SandwichBuilders` could throw some kind of `IncompleteSandwichException` if not completed correctly when `.getSandwich()` is called.

**Note:** *with properly named construction methods, you don't need to do anything in a specific order.*

Or you could use a `FactoryMethod` pattern: *When the number of steps would fit into a single method call with a reasonable number of arguments, and the object should be guaranteed to be a complete state.*

```
BreadSlice bs1 = new BreadSlice();
BreadSlice bs2 = new BreadSlice();
List<Cheese> cheeses = new ArrayList<Cheese>();
...
Sandwich s = SandwichBuilder.buildSandwich(bs1, cheeses, bs2);
```

Or use the `Constructor`: *which is a specialized case of `FactoryMethod` pattern*

```
Sandwich s = new Sandwich(bs1, cheeses, bs2);
```

overloaded constructor to allow for cheese addition:

```
Sandwich s = new Sandwich(bs1, bs2);
s.addCheese(new CheeseSlice());
...
```

There are lots of ways to do this depending on how strict you want the construction to be.
For example, you can make the `Sandwich` implementation an `inner class` of the `Factory/Builder` object and make its constructor `private` so it can't be instantiated in-correctly.

Comment: Great solution, but could be better if your constructor would accept the two bread slices: `SandwichBuilder sb = new SandwichBuilder(new BreadSlice(), new BreadSlice());`. This way you don't need to check for IncompleteSandwichException on the `getSandwich`. As you said, there lots of solutions for this.

Comment: `SandwichBuilder` is a utility class, and that method following the `FactoryMethodPattern` the method is `static` there is not `constructor` for that class. Note that the method is on the `Class` not an instance of the class. See my last solution using the `Sandwich` class constructor as a specialized `FactoryMethodPattern`

Answer (score 6):

I think the [Builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) pattern could be a good choice here.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented the solution using

> Template pattern.

Though the solution is in C# it can easily be modified to run in Java environment.

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DeliverSandwitch(new MinimumCheese());
            DeliverSandwitch(new MixCheese());
            DeliverSandwitch(new DoubleSwissCheese());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void DeliverSandwitch(BaseSandwitch customSandwitch)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(customSandwitch.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
            foreach (string layer in customSandwitch.Layers)
                Console.WriteLine(layer);

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        public abstract class BaseSandwitch
        {
            List<string> layers = new List<string>();
            protected virtual CheeseType DefaultCheese { get { return CheeseType.PlainCheese; } }
            public abstract string Name { get; }
            public BaseSandwitch()
            {
                SandwitchTemplate();
            }

            private void SandwitchTemplate()
            {
                AddBaseBread();
                AddCheese(DefaultCheese);
                AddAdditionalCheese();
                AddTopBread();
            }

            private void AddTopBread()
            {
                layers.Add("Top bread");
            }

            public abstract void AddAdditionalCheese();

            private void AddBaseBread()
            {
                layers.Add("Base bread");
            }

            protected void AddCheese(CheeseType cheeseType)
            {
                layers.Add(cheeseType.ToString());
            }

            public IEnumerable<string> Layers { get { return layers; } }
        }

        class MinimumCheese : BaseSandwitch
        {
            public override string Name { get { return "Minimum cheese Sandwitch"; }}
            public override void AddAdditionalCheese()
            {
                // I come with no additional cheese
            }

            // I do not like PlainCheese. Replacing with CheddarCheese
            protected override CheeseType DefaultCheese
            {
                get { return CheeseType.CheddarCheese; }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// I am ok with default cheese and would like to have other cheese as well
        /// </summary>
        class MixCheese : BaseSandwitch
        {
            public override string Name { get { return "Mix cheese Sandwitch"; } }
            public override void AddAdditionalCheese()
            {
                AddCheese(CheeseType.CheddarCheese);
                AddCheese(CheeseType.SwissCheese);
            }
        }

        class DoubleSwissCheese : BaseSandwitch
        {
            public override string Name { get { return "Double Swiss Cheese Sandwitch"; } }
            public override void AddAdditionalCheese()
            {
                // Adding another layer of swiss cheese
                AddCheese(CheeseType.SwissCheese);
            }

            // I like swiss cheese by default instead of PlainCheese
            protected override CheeseType DefaultCheese
            {
                get { return CheeseType.SwissCheese; }
            }
        }

        public enum CheeseType { PlainCheese, SwissCheese, CheddarCheese };
    }
}
```

Comment: This guarantees that both top and bottom bread are always created. However, you should have a positive number of chesses, so I guess `NoChesse` is not applicable in this case.

Comment: @Jose Rui Santos - thanks for pointing out that. I have modified the code to support at least one cheese layer. There can be few variations to it depending on the need. 
I have made cheese as an enum to be statically typed instead of using string.

Comment: this object orientation run amok, also it is `Sandwich`, no t, there is no magic involved.